# Error 10002 when trying to login with Facebook on iOS

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to fix a bug in Facebook login in an iOS app I'm working on. Frustrating thing is that is was working fine, and then my client changed the bundle ID on Facebook and in the app, and now I can no longer get the app to connect.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
let accountType = accountStore.accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier(ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook)
let options = [ACFacebookAppIdKey:"##############",
               ACFacebookPermissionsKey:"email",
               ACFacebookAudienceKey: ACFacebookAudienceFriends]

accountStore.requestAccessToAccountsWithType(accountType, options: options) { (granted, error) in
```

When I call this, I get the error:

```
Error Domain=com.apple.accounts Code=10002
```

I've tried with a couple of accounts. This is on the iOS 10.1 and 9.2 simulators.

I've confirmed the following:

- BundleID on Facebook is the same as in the app
- Facebook app ID is set correctly in the info.plist
- "Native or desktop app?" on Facebook is "Yes"
- "Your app is currently live and available to the public." on Facebook
  is "Yes"
- My Facebook account information is correct

Any suggestions?

Comment: did you setup your account in setting ?

Comment: In the Settings app on the (simulated) phone? Yes, it is set up and correct. I tried with two accounts.